# Passing user input into python requests body

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Trying to get host name input from user and call that into the requests body. There should be a way of doing this but looks like hostname_from_user does not substitute input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import requests

hostname_from_user = input("enter name of host")
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
}

data = '{ "filter": { "pattern": hostname_from_user+"*"} }'
print(data)
```

```
output:
enter name of host: google.com
{ "filter": { "pattern": hostname_from_user+"*"} }
```

```
Desired output:
enter name of host: google.com
{ "filter": { "pattern": google.com*"} }
```

Comment: What do you mean "invalid literal"? `data` is just a *string*, that happens to contain almost-JSON. Are you expecting to interpolate the values of attributes (`self.host`) and function calls (`match(pattern, host.name)`)? If so, where do those come from and do you have any code to make that happen? Please give a [mre].

Comment: Are you trying to substitute the character sequence `hostname_from_user` for the value in the variable with the same name? If so, take a look at [formatted strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Python 3.6+, the solution is very simple and requires using f-string.

Use `{}` around `hostname_from_use` and prefix entire string with f as follows.

```
data = f'{"filter": { "pattern": {hostname_from_user}+"*"} }'
```

A general solution of doing this would be

```
data = f'{"filter": { "pattern": %s+"*"} }' % hostname_from_user
```

Comment: `data = { "filter": { "pattern": f"{hostname_from_user}"+"*"} }` this worked